# phone working on its own

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a problem that my android mobile is randomly working like itself making calls, typing messages, opening apps randomly.
I have tried factory reset and data wipe.

Could anyone help me out here.

Comment: Does the screen have any scratches, cracks, anything wrong with it?

Comment: `typing messages` -- actual full messages or just random keys?  If the latter it sounds like a screen problem as the other comment says.

Comment: No. My screen was new.. I replace with new one. Typing messages just a random. And itself sending photos to contacts ransomly

Comment: My screen was broken previously and now its new. I noticed that ifif I lock the phone, these things are not happening.

Comment: How long ago was it replaced? Could be a faulty digitizer or problem with the installation.

Comment: I think the screen was not replaces very good.

Comment: No before that replacement also I faced the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

its a faulty digitizer or the screen is faulty. my recommendation  go for a replacement if you still have the warranty period . Anyway, its a pure hardware problem, don't reset your phone, as you are going to earn absolutely nothing